# C# Combo Box Fill from Class or Method

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, combobox

My concern is how to add comboBox1.DataSource and comboBox1.DisplayMember both codes in the class it self and how to pass combobox name as parameter from the form?

Form Code

```
SClass.Database db = new NSClass.Database();
db.comboFill(@"Select UserName from Staff");
comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(db.tableNewGet, null);
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "UserName";
```

NS Class Code

```
private DataTable tableNew = new DataTable();      
        public DataTable tableNewGet
        {
            get { return tableNew; }
            set { tableNew = value; }
        }

public void comboFill(string query)
        {            
            {
                using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, cs))
                   da.Fill(tableNew);
            }             
        }
```

Comment: *"I have three questions"*. Then post three separate questions, not one question that requires three answers.

Comment: It's related to same question, that's why I have mentioned properly with my research

Comment: Either you have one specific question or you don't. Related questions are not the same question. If you need three answers, post three questions. That's how this site works.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by this: _I will get blank columns if I run same code for multiple times for different query. How to avoid that?_ You will need to provide the specific queries and demonstrate the output. Different queries _will_ by their definition return different values!

Comment: @ChrisSchaller I have edit my problem to single question. Kindly check and let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WinForms you have a number of options for `ComboBox`, ultimately if you are not going to set `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` yourself, but you want to allow *dynamic* queries, then you will need to write some code to resolve this.

You could create a helper method on the `NS` class:

```
public void comboFill(ComboBox combo, string query, string displayMember)
{   
    this.comboFill(query);
    combo.DataSource = new BindingSource(this.tableNewGet, null);
    combo.DisplayMember = displayMember;       
}
```

Then your code in the form should look like this:

```
SClass.Database db = new NSClass.Database();
db.comboFill(comboBox1, @"Select UserName from Staff", "UserName");
```

---

> I will get blank columns if I run same code for multiple times for different query. How to avoid that?

Your code simply executes the `query` sql and dumps it into a table structure that matches the output. The blanks come from your query, if you do not want blanks in the results, then adjust your query to omit these rows.

You will need to post the specific query and the output if you want specific advice, but in general it is not the code's fault that you wanted to query blank values.

---

> Does this code prevent database injection issues?

Regarding *Database Injection* => This is only a real concern if the user interface provides a mechanism where the *query* string can be manipulated by the user. In this case you are safe from that, I am not going to say this is *"**the** correct way to write it"* but this specific code should be OK for now.

using *TableAdapters* is a recommended way to prevent injection attacks when using ADO.Net, but your implementation of `MySqlDataAdapter` might still facilitate injection attacks if you do not pass through a *parameterised* query. If you only provide a generic string literal for both the `ConnectionString` and the `Query` then it is highly likely that elsewhere in your code you might be opening yourself to injection attacks.

You might consider ORMs like *Entity Framework* or *nHibernate* if you want to further protect yourself from Injection issues and to automate parameterisation of the actual SQL that is executed. (The ORM will generate the SQL for you from LINQ queries)

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear explanation. Regarding the blank line concern. I will explain: This is the issue `db.comboFill(comboBox1, @"Select UserName from Staff", "UserName");`
`db.comboFill(comboBox2, @"Select UserType from Staff", "UserTyep");` If I add two times to get two combo box filled. I will get few blank lines at bottom of comboBox1 and few blank lines at top of the comboBox2. This is because of the get method from `public DataTable tableNewGet` I guess. How to avoid or remove blank lines?

Comment: I just want to confirm you that the table column doesn't have null rows

Comment: The blank lines issue is specifically a data issue, I can only speculate why the null is there without being able to see the underlying raw data that is returned from your query. You should post that as a different question and include the SQL query, the raw result and a screenshot showing the blank rows.